# Continuity of normed linear spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A: X \rightarrow Y$ be linear and $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear
>   spaces. Show that $A$ is continuous if and only if $A$ is bounded.

Solution:

$A$ is bounded if and only if there is a $M \geq 0$ such that $||Ax|| \leq M||x||$ for every $x \in X$.

Comment: Well that's the definition of bounded.  What else have you done?

Comment: Try baby steps: Show that $A$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if it is bounded. Then show that if it is continuous at $0$, then it is continuous at any point.